# How do I fix this dark spot on my model?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I'm working on this model in Blender 2.79, and I noticed a dark spot on the top of the model when I go into *Texture* view.

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I found out that I didn't put a lamp below the model, and that's what caused it to have dark spots.

Comment: Check your normals.